# Add an action to navigate to page within a pdf given a Combo Box field selection using iText5

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, combobox, itext

I am trying to add a pdfFormField combobox to the top of each page of a large pdf that when a given choice is selected it will take the user to the page at the start of that section.

The choices are the titles of each section of the document and export values are the pages I wish to navigate to.

```
String[] options = new String[links.size()];
        String[] exports = new String[links.size()];
        for(int i=links.size()-1 ;i>=0; i--){
            Pair<String,Integer> itr = links.get(i); 
            options[links.size()-1-i]= itr.first;
            exports[links.size()-1-i] = Integer.toString(itr.second);
        }
```

I have successfully applied the combo box to each page of the document using the following code but am unable to find a method that allows me to navigate about the document based on the export value of choice from the combo box.

```
PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getOverContent(pageNum);

BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont();
        PdfWriter writer = content.getPdfWriter();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(right-150f,top-15f,right-70f,top-2f);
        TextField tf = new TextField(writer, rect, "Headers");
        PdfFormField select = PdfFormField.createEmpty(writer);
        tf.setFont(bf);
        tf.setBorderStyle(PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_BEVELED);
        tf.setVisibility(TextField.VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT);
        tf.setBorderColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
        tf.setChoiceExports(exports);
        tf.setChoices(options);
        tf.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        try {
            select.addKid(tf.getComboField());
                          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
        } 
       
        pdfStamper.addAnnotation(select,pageNum);
```

Due to the constraints of the project I am largely using the iText5 library for pdf manipulation and the use of a combo box is required due to the large number of sections within the >1000 page document.

Comment: This would probably only be possible if you use javascript. However JS is not supported in many PDF Viewers so this solution will probably only work in *dobe products. If you want a general solution add an overview page with links or something like that...

Comment: @dunccam is it an option for you to have not combobox, but a list of clickable pargraphs which will navigate to the requested pages?

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk no it is not, the current implementation uses clickable links across the top of the page but if the number of links exceeds the width of the page it does not look very professional and does not work properly (hence the need for a drop down menu). Additionally this combo box is to be printed on every page of the document for ease of navigation

Comment: I believe that @Lonzak is right: one should either use JS actions, which may not be supported in certain Pdf-viewers, or implement a workaround: a) introduce a table of links at the end of the document; b) navigate to this table one one clicks on the area above the page's content